# SQL case - if a value is equal to something then do something

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is part of my SQL query.

```
SELECT 

c.fullname AS Course,
gi.itemname AS Activity,
CONCAT(ROUND(gg.finalgrade,1) , '%') AS Grade,   
cmc.completionstate,
gi.itemmodule,

concat('<a target="_new" href="localhost/moodle/mod/quiz/view.php?id=',cm.id,'">View this Activity</a>') AS 'Link'
```

I want to display the above link when gi.itemmodule = quiz, and a different link(..moodle/mod/scorm..) when gi.itemmodule = scorm, etc...

I am thinking this needs a `CASE` statement here but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case gi.itemmodule
     when 'quiz' 
       then concat(<onelink>)
     when 'scorm'
       then concat(<oneotherlink>)
     else concat(<defaultlink>)
end as 'Link'
```

you could also do the case when in the concat, if only one part of the concat should be changed.

something like

```
concat('<a target="_new" href="',
       (case gi.itemmodule
        when 'quiz' 
          then 'value of href'
        when 'scorm'
           then 'another value of href'
        else 'defaultvalue of href'
        end), 
        cm.id,
        '">View this Activity</a>') as 'Link'
```

Which will avoid code duplication, but may be harder to read...

With the sample given, it seems that you could just do (but not sure)

```
concat('<a target="_new" href="localhost/moodle/mod/',gi.itemmodule, '/view.php?id=',cm.id,'">View this Activity</a>') AS 'Link'
```

or if some itemmodule are usefull for link, but not all

```
concat('<a target="_new" href="localhost/moodle/mod/',
        (case when gi.itemmodule in ('scorm', 'quiz', 'asdf') 
             then gi.itemmodule
             else 'defaultValue'
        end), 
       '/view.php?id=',
       cm.id,
       '">View this Activity</a>') AS 'Link'
```

Comment: thanks Raphael this looks great, but I do not only have 2 options, there are different values for 'quiz', 'scorm', 'assignment', etc. there are about 5 values in total. would that not need to be slightly different then? thanks

Comment: @user1525612 I changed my examples with more than two cases. By the way, added a last solution which could makes things easier (but it depends on your datas / needs)

Answer (score 0):

You should't really build a link in a SQL query. Use the moodle_url() function instead

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            c.fullname AS Course,
            gi.itemname AS Activity,
            " . $DB->sql_concat('ROUND(gg.finalgrade,1)' , '%') . " AS Grade,   
            cmc.completionstate,
            gi.itemmodule,
            ...
        ";
```

$DB->sql_concat() is a cross database function in Moodle for using concat.

```
$activities = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
foreach ($activities as $activity) {
    if ($activity->itemmodule == 'quiz') {
        // Custom url
        $url = new moodle_url('/mod/quiz/view.php', array('id' => $activity->cmid));
    } else {
        // Module url
        $url = new moodle_url('/mod/' . $activity->itemmodule . '/view.php', array('id' => $activity->cmid));
    }
    $link = html_writer::link($url, get_string('view', 'mod_' . $activity->itemmodule));
    echo $link;
}
```

Comment: Hi Russel, thanks for this! I am using the custom sql reports plugin in conjunction with configurable reports, though.